# Perl read file and split into variables issue

Tags: perl

Must look dumb, but I have a little Perl code to read a file with contents like this:

```
John|Doe
John|Smith
No|Name
Ozzy|Osbourne
```

I want to read the file and get the data as variables `$firstname` `$lastname`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(DB, "$ARGV[0]") || die ":: Can't open database.\n";

my $line;

foreach $line (<DB>){
  chomp $line;
  $line =~ s/^\s+//;
  $line =~ s/\s+$//;
  my ($firstname, $lastname) = split /|/, $line;
  print "Firstname: $firstname - Lastname: $lastname\n";
}
```

What I get is:

```
Firstname: J - Lastname: o
Firstname: J - Lastname: o
Firstname: N - Lastname: o
Firstname: O - Lastname: z
```

First and second characters. Where am I wrong?

Comment: same result, tried also "|"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split takes a regular expression. If you want to match `|` literally, you need to escape it.

```
split /\|/, $line;
```

Comment: did not know that, gotta love perl

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using split, with regex

```
open(FH,test.txt);
my @array=<FH>;

foreach(@array)
{
$_=~ m/(\w+)\|(\w+)/;
print "Firstname: $1 ,Lastname: $2 \n";
}
```